# wifi card in 1u rack

Tags: linux, networking

So I bought a 1u server with the intention of putting it into a data centre. However before I get to this step I need to develop on it for a couple of months in my house. I think noise if going to be an issue from what I've read and heard on the videos so my thoughts are I'm going to put this thing in my basement or roof. However connectivity then becomes an issues. I was wondering if I can put a wifi card (PCI Express) card into one of these things. The antennas look a bit big i'm not sure the card looks like it will fit to be honest. Is this a viable solution. The hope is that then I will be able to get this wifi card connecting to my internet router then I'll be remoting into the server via wifi as well? Will the 1u PCI card fit and does anyone see a problem with this approach?

Thanks

Comment: You may need a half height card. Check your server specs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most if not all servers will take a wifi PCIe card yes, and most server OS's will support them too - there's really no major issue with this. Obviously a wired connection would be better but I can see why you might need this option.

Comment: Thanks for the response Chopper, I tried to upvote you however i can't yet sorry... Also the server comes with two network ports do you think it would be easier getting a wireless router and connecting it via the ports or using a dedicated wifi card?

Comment: @MarMan29 Why not USB? They're everywhere and cheap.